# Arduino / C++: Pass object to constructor by reference

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to pass two objects into the constructor of another object.

I created a `ClimateController` class.

Each `ClimateController` instance should have a `DHT` and a `Relay` object.

- The `DHT` object would be a *shared* instance for each `ClimateController` object, since there is just one sensor.
- The `Relay` object should be a *unique* instance for each `ClimateController` instance, since each controller should have its own relay.

I wrote a sketch but currently it's not working. I hope someone can help me with this. I am new to C++ but have experience with Java. Maybe I'm thinking to much in a Java way...

This is my sketch:

```
#include "Relay.h"
#include "libs/DHT-sensor-library/DHT.h"
#include "libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h"

DHT* dht;
Relay* relay1;
Relay* relay2;
ClimateController* heatingController;
ClimateController* coolingController;

void setup() {
    pinMode(PIN0, INPUT);
    pinMode(PIN1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PIN2, OUTPUT);

    dht = new DHT(PIN0, DHT22, 1);
    relay1 = new Relay(PIN1, false);
    relay2 =  new Relay(PIN2, false);

    heatingController = new ClimateController(
            relay1,
            dht,
            0.0,
            30.0
    );

    coolingController = new ClimateController(
            relay2,
            dht,
            32.0,
            100.0
    );
}

void loop() {
    heatingController.poll(;)
    coolingController.poll();
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following exceptions:

> ====================[ Build | untitled1 | Debug ]===============================
>   /home/joris/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/183.5429.37/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake
>   --build /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/cmake-build-debug --target untitled1 -- -j 2 [ 87%] Built target uno_CORE [ 91%] Building CXX
>   object CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/untitled1_untitled1.ino.cpp.obj
>   /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/untitled1.ino: In function ‘void
>   setup()’: /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/untitled1.ino:27:5:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘ClimateController::ClimateController(Relay*&, DHT*&, double, double)’
>        );
>        ^ In file included from /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/untitled1.ino:3:0:
>   /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:22:5:
>   note: candidate: ClimateController::ClimateController(Relay, DHT,
>   float, float)
>        ClimateController(Relay relay, DHT sensor, float minValue, float maxValue);
>        ^ /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:22:5:
>   note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Relay*’ to ‘Relay’
>   /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:11:7:
>   note: candidate: ClimateController::ClimateController(const
>   ClimateController&)  class ClimateController {
>          ^ /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:11:7:
>   note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
>   /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/untitled1.ino:34:5: error: no
>   matching function for call to
>   ‘ClimateController::ClimateController(Relay*&, DHT*&, double, double)’
>        );
>        ^ In file included from /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/untitled1.ino:3:0:
>   /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:22:5:
>   note: candidate: ClimateController::ClimateController(Relay, DHT,
>   float, float)
>        ClimateController(Relay relay, DHT sensor, float minValue, float maxValue);
>        ^ /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:22:5:
>   note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Relay*’ to ‘Relay’
>   /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:11:7:
>   note: candidate: ClimateController::ClimateController(const
>   ClimateController&)  class ClimateController {
>          ^ /home/joris/CLionProjects/untitled1/libs/Wagter_ClimateController/ClimateController.h:11:7:
>   note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
>   CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/build.make:66: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/untitled1_untitled1.ino.cpp.obj' failed
>   make[3]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/untitled1_untitled1.ino.cpp.obj] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:173: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/all' failed make[2]:** 
>   [CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/all] Error 2 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:185:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/rule' failed make[1]: 
>   **[CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/rule] Error 2 Makefile:157: recipe for
>   target 'untitled1' failed make: *** [untitled1] Error 2

This is the `ClimateController.h` file:

```
#ifndef _CLIMATE_CONTROLLER_h
#define _CLIMATE_CONTROLLER_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Relay.h"
#include "libs/Adafruit_Sensor/Adafruit_Sensor.h"
#include "libs/DHT-sensor-library/DHT.h"

class ClimateController {

protected:
    Relay relay;
    DHT sensor;
    float minValue;
    float maxValue;
    float currentValue;
    bool state;

public:
    ClimateController(Relay relay, DHT sensor, float minValue, float maxValue);

    void poll();

    float getMinValue();

    float getMaxValue();

    float getCurrentValue();

    bool getState();
};

#endif
```

This is my `ClimateController.cpp` file:

```
#include "ClimateController.h"

ClimateController::ClimateController(Relay relay, DHT sensor, float minValue, float maxValue) {
    this->relay = relay;
    this->sensor = sensor;
    this->minValue = minValue;
    this->maxValue = maxValue;
    this->currentValue = 0;
}

float ClimateController::getCurrentValue() {
    return this->currentValue;
}

float ClimateController::getMinValue() {
    return  this->minValue;
}

float ClimateController::getMaxValue() {
    return  this->maxValue;
}

bool ClimateController::getState() {
    return this->state;
}

void ClimateController::poll() {
    //@TODO: implement poll method
}
```

**Thanks to @fonZ I fixed it. Here is my corrected code:**

```
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Relay.h>

class ClimateController {
  protected:
    const Relay &relay;
    DHT *sensor;
    double minValue;
    double maxValue;
    double currentValue;
    bool state;

  public:
    ClimateController(const Relay &relay, DHT *sensor, double minValue, double maxValue)
        : sensor(sensor), relay(relay) {
        this->minValue = minValue,
        this->maxValue = maxValue;
        this->currentValue = 0;
    }
    double getCurrentValue() {
        return currentValue;
    }
    double getMinValue() {
        return  minValue;
    }
    double getMaxValue() {
        return maxValue;
    }
    bool getState() {
        return state;
    }
    void poll() {
        //@TODO: Implement poll method
    }
};

ClimateController *heatingController;
ClimateController *coolingController;

void setup() {
    pinMode(PIN0, INPUT);
    pinMode(PIN1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PIN2, OUTPUT);

    DHT *dht = new DHT(PIN0, DHT22, 1);

    heatingController = new ClimateController(Relay(PIN1, false), dht, 0.0, 30.0);
    coolingController = new ClimateController(Relay(PIN2, false), dht, 32.0, 100.0);
}

void loop() {
    heatingController->poll();
    coolingController->poll();
}
```

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to ‘ClimateController::ClimateController(Relay*&, DHT*&, double, double)’ );` you use pointers, allocate the memory, then you use objects. The error is quote clear -  you pass a pointer to Relay and a pointer to DHT, yet your constructor is taking objects `ClimateController(Relay relay, DHT sensor, float minValue, float maxValue)`.

Comment: `The DHT object would be a shared instance` In that case, it should be a static variable. But then why should you pass it through constructor?

Comment: @GauravSingh I don't really see why it should be static. I want to pass it through the constructor because that would be the best practice IMO. All objects that another object depends on should be passed through the constructor. AKA dependency-injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you make no distinction between normal objects, references and pointers. In Java everything is a pointer, so there is no need for different syntax. In C++ there is a big difference.

Create a pointer on the heap: (if you don't delete it at the end of the scope in which it was created, it will keep on living)

```
DHT *dht = new DHT(PIN0, DHT22, 1); // this is a pointer
```

Create an object on the stack: (you can see this as a local variable because as soon as the scope ends, your object is automatically deleted)

```
DHT dht = DHT(PIN0, DHT22, 1);
```

This is a pointer that points to the memory that was created with the previous call, i.e. DHT dht = ...

```
DHT *dhtPointer = &dht;
```

The following is a reference to the memory that was created in the first call:

```
DHT &dhtRef = dht;
```

You see the syntax is different right? Then you also see that your constructor is not taking pointers, which you are provinding:

```
DHT *dht = new DHT(PIN0, DHT22, 1); // pointer
// sensor in the constructor below is just an object, not a pointer, while dht is a pionter
ClimateController(Relay relay, DHT sensor, float minValue, float maxValue);
```

Instead you need either pass an object, not a pointer, for relay and sensor. Or you change your constructor to take pointers:

```
ClimateController(Relay *relay, DHT *sensor, float minValue, float maxValue);
```

In the case of relay you could just pass the constructed object as a const reference:

```
ClimateController(const Relay &relay, DHT *sensor, float minValue, float maxValue);
```

Which will allow you to just pass it like this:

```
new ClimateController(Relay(PIN1, false), dht, 0.0, 30.0);
```

I hope that clears up some of the doubts you have.

Comment: Thanks for giving me these insights with a concrete example for my own code and putting it in perspective with Java. My code is now free of compilation errors. I updated my question with the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the members to be references like this

```
protected:
   Relay& relay;
   DHT& sensor;
```

use member initializer list to set reference in cpp (note that the parameters are references too so change it in .h too)

```c
ClimateController::ClimateController(Relay& _relay, DHT& _sensor, float minValue, float maxValue) 
   : relay(_relay), sensor(_sensor) {
    this->minValue = minValue;
    this->maxValue = maxValue;
    this->currentValue = 0;
}
```

in .ino create `dht` as global variable

```
DHT dhtDHT(PIN0, DHT22, 1);
```

and pass it to constructor like you do it now

```
heatingController = new ClimateController(relay1, dht, 0.0, 30.0);
```

Comment: Please correct the typo: relay(relay) (missing _) ;)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need. I will check if it works later and then accept the answer ;-)